# How to programatically insert link at current position in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

In my app, I have a specific dialog to create internal links. After user finishes filling the dialog I want to programatically insert generated link to current caret position in the editor. So far I've been using SummerNote and there it is easy:

```
editor.summernote('createLink', {
     text: linkTitle,
     url: url
});
```

In CKEditor 5 I found this method which seems like it could do what I need:

```
doc.enqueueChanges(() => {
    editor.data.insertContent(content, doc.selection);
});
```

My problem is that I don't know how to create this "content" parameter. I tried to create a link in HTML and pass it there, but that doesn't work.

I also tried to create an instance of [LinkElement](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_link_linkelement-LinkElement.html), but that class doesn't seem to exist in the JS runtime (I'm running CKEditor from build, not from sources).

It's not clear to me if this is even possible without writing a plugin for CKEditor (which seems to me like an overkill).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### After 1.0.0-beta (March 2018):

To insert some data into an editor, simply use a "change block":

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
    const insertPosition = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
    writer.insertText( linkText, { linkHref: linkUrl }, insertPosition );
} );
```

where `linkText` and `linkUrl` are variables that you should provide from your custom UI.

The above will work well for collapsed selection. The linked text will be inserted at caret position.

The big difference introduced in 1.0.0-beta is that we are providing the `writer` object in `change()` calls, so you don't need to (and should not) use framework classes constructors directly.

You can also use `editor.model.insertContent` in a similar way that you proposed:

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
    const linkedText = writer.createText( linkText, { linkHref: linkUrl } );
    editor.model.insertContent( linkedText, editor.model.document.selection );
} );
```

This will work properly also if the selection is not collapsed, as `insertContent` does a little bit more (for example, if selection was not collapsed and was between two paragraphs, selection contents will be removed and paragraphs merged).

### Before 1.0.0-beta

[`DataController#insertContent()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_controller_datacontroller-DataController.html#insertContent) accepts model's [`DocumentFragment`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_documentfragment-DocumentFragment.html) or [`Node`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_node-Node.html) (so [`Element`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_element-Element.html) or [`Text`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_text-Text.html) – *I've just noticed that this info is missing in the API docs*).

Unfortunately, right now you need to have access to `Element`'s or `Text`'s constructors in order to create them. This means that you need to [build CKEditor 5 from source](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#Scenario-2-Building-from-source) instead of using existing builds. This isn't hard, but it's indeed an overkill. Therefore, we're working now on [exposing a sufficient part of the API in the existing classes](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/667) so that you could write simple integration code like this without building CKEditor 5 into your app.

Anyway, if you'll configure webpack (or simply fork an existing build) you can write a simple function for inserting a linked text:

```
import Text from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/text';

function insertLink( linkText, linkHref ) {
    const text = new Text( linkText, { linkHref } );

    editor.document.enqueueChanges( () => {
        editor.data.insertContent( text, editor.document.selection );
    } );
}
```

Comment: I'm using the "after" version above. The problem is that if this is the first thing I do on a document, the cursor does not move to the end of the inserted content. But, if I move the cursor one time, then further inserts do move the cursor. What am I missing?

Comment: And should we be doing editor.editing.view.focus() as well? That is indicated as something that should be done after a menu operation (I insert due to a menu option).

Comment: You can either use `editor.editing.view.focus()` and/or `evt.preventDefault()` on `mousedown` in your menu. CKEditor 5's buttons use both to handle also a case when there was no focus in the editor before the item was clicked.

Comment: As for the problem with seleciton, it may be releated to the focus issue. But IDK – you'd need to make a demo.

Comment: Would you have a similar example for how to insert an html string so that it would get handled as if a user pasted it in? Example: '<b>Some bolded text</b>', with your example it gets input as a literal string and does not actually bold the text.