# CKEditor 5 - insert text

Tags: ckeditor5

Is it possible to insert text into the editor at current selection?

I have tried

```
import Text from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/text';

function insertText() {
  let text = new Text('test');
  ckEditor.model.insertContent(text, ckEditor.model.document.selection);
}
```

where `ckEditor` is the editor object returned from `ClassicEditor.create`

code runs without error, but nothing happens

I have managed to get similar code to work from within a plugin, but here I am trying to inject the text from the host app

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have managed to get similar code to work from within a plugin, but here I am trying to inject the text from the host app

It worked when you implemented it as a plugin because then you used the `Text` class from the same package which the `ClassicEditor` depend on to.

When you tried to do the same when using a bundle with the editor, you unknowingly duplicated the whole `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine` package. One instance of this package was bundled into the editor, and the second one you just used later on (in the snippet which you showed), so webpack imported it again.

This is an environmental issue that we have at the moment – [you can't add plugins to a CKEditor 5 build](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/667).

Fortunately, we noticed this problem a long time ago and much has been improved since then. Inserting a text does not require importing anything:

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
    const insertPosition = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
    writer.insertText( 'foo', insertPosition );
} );
```

The [`writer.insertText()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html#function-insertText) method can also insert a text with [attributes](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#text-attributes), so e.g. you can insert bolded text like this:

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
    const insertPosition = editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
    writer.insertText( 'foo', { bold: true }, insertPosition );
} );
```

Or if you want to insert a link, then see [How to programatically insert link at current position in CKEditor 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611200/how-to-programatically-insert-link-at-current-position-in-ckeditor-5)

Comment: its insert fine from other component into editor but after that focus not working means it loss the focus and keyboard need to click again to typing in it

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me, using the editor returned by (ready):

```js
insertTag(tag: string) {
  const insertPosition = this.editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
  const viewFragment = this.editor.data.processor.toView(`<p>${tag}</p>`);
  const modelFragment = this.editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
  this.mod.insertContent(modelFragment);
}
```

See also the [the font](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/1c116a001a7361ef8fa56ab48ccdb44c27b1695d/packages/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/model.js#L295-L425).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, to enable the input focus after inserting the text, add this code.

```js
editor.editing.view.focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is the right way...

in react can not use the **editor** outside 
so i put editor instance in a state

```
 onBlur={(event, editor) => {
                    //console.log('Blur.', editor);
                    ckInstance(editor)

                }}
```

and then use it through out the onclick and js file like

```
 const onBlureAddText = () => {
      editorState.model.change(writer => {
          const insertPosition = editorState.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
          writer.insertText('<Tag:1>', insertPosition);
      });
```